# JSplitPane set resizable false

Tags: java, swing, border

How to make `JSplitPane` to resizable `false`? I didn't want to resize the `JSplitPane`, I used it for the border of this pane. Is there any other way to create same border structure to split a panel vertically into two parts.

Comment: Disable the split pane. See below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override the JSplitPane methodes `getDividerLocation()` and `getLastDividerLocation` and return a constant value.

```
JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT){
    private final int location = 100;
    {
        setDividerLocation( location );
    }
    @Override
    public int getDividerLocation() {
        return location ;
    }
    @Override
    public int getLastDividerLocation() {
        return location ;
    }
};
```

Comment: @Tapas Bose, no need to extend the split pane class.

Comment: @camickr But that's exactly what this solution does, it extends JSpiltPane with an anonymous class.

Answer (score 27):

```
splitPane.setEnabled( false );
```

Comment: but with nimbus i see no border if it is disabled. :(

Comment: this solution is simple and awesome

Comment: This disables subcomponents if they inherit the parent status of enabled/disable. e.g. a jlist may be disabled from being able to be selected.

Comment: @Mgamerz, a JList works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. The setEnabled() method only applies to the component, not child components. For example see the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) for an example with a JList.

Comment: @camickr When I disable this split pane some of my sub components are no longer selectable. I cannot pick items in a Jlist and a sub-splitpane doesn't have the cursor change to indicate it is movable while it still is. Removing the disable makes it work normally again.

Comment: @Mgamerz, You have custom code that isn't working properly. I gave you a link to the demo code from the Swing tutorial and I already stated it works fine for me. If the tutorial code doesn't work then m\Maybe you have a version / OS bug. This is NOT the way enable is designed to work. That is you can't use disabled on a JPanel to disable all components on the panel. If you have a question then create a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post a real question on the forum. Stating something doesn't work without posting code means nothing. It is probably your code, not Swing.

Answer (score 7):

For preventing users to resize the panes you can also set the divider size to zero.

```
splitPane.setDividerSize(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider for using [Compound Borders](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#custom) with [EtchedBorder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#demo)

Answer (score 2):

```
final double pos = split.getDividers().get(0).getPosition();
split.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0,
            Number arg1, Number arg2) {
        split.getDividers().get(0).setPosition(pos);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated un @camickr answer comments, disabling the whole split pane can disable contained components interactive behavior (for example, they won't show their interactive cursors on hover)

instead, if using BasicSplitPaneUI, you can disable the divider from the UI

```
public class MySplitPane extends JSplitPane {

    public void setResizable(boolean resizable) {
        BasicSplitPaneUIui = (BasicSplitPaneUI) this.getUI();
        ui.getDivider().setEnabled(resizable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@TrogloGeek's answer works best, to avoid problems with the disabled splitpane.

For example, if you want to make a pane that is 'onetouchexpandable', but not resizable, you can use this:

```
public class FixedExpandableSplitPane extends JSplitPane {

    public FixedExpandableSplitPane(int orientation) {
        super(orientation);
        setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        BasicSplitPaneUI ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI) this.getUI();
        ui.getDivider().setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```